# page not found error in Django using a filter query {return Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-published_date')}

Tags: django

I am making my first django practice project I have a view called PostListview :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from blog.models import Post, Comment
from blog.forms import PostForm,CommentForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import(TemplateView,ListView,DetailView,CreateView,UpdateView,
                                    DeleteView)


class AboutView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'about.html'

class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post

    def get_queryset(self):

        return Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-published_date')
```

I have this in in the urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from blog import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.PostListView.as_view(), name= 'post_list'),
```

And this is the template which is calling this view.

```
<li class="navbar-brand bigbrand" ><a href="{% url 'post_list %'}">My Tech Blog</a></li>
```

This view is also set as the default home view and it opens fine at the time i open the site url (localhost) but when I am clicking "My Tech blog " it gives a 404 error.

This is the main urls.py :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib.auth import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'',include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'accounts/login/$',views.login, name = 'login'),
    url(r'accounts/logout/$',views.logout, name = 'logout',kwargs={'next_page':'/'}),

]
```

Comment: `published_date__lte=timezone.now()` are you afraid of posts from the future? What's the point of this filter? And please show main urls.py

Comment: @IvanStarostin - I am just following a tutorial don't know much about it but i guess it is to show only the published date

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
url(r'^$',views.PostListView.as_view(), name= 'post_list'),
```

with

```
url(r'',views.PostListView.as_view(), name= 'post_list'),
```

Comment: Hi Jagjeet, this works. Can you please tell the difference between the two and why it didn't work for me but it did work for the tutor.

Comment: @Jhonty4 Does your index url work now? login/logout urls?

Comment: @IvanStarostin - No, these urls are not working now.

Comment: @Jhonty4 because `url(r''` means _any url_. So you are always falling into post_list no matter which url is opened. Please update your question to make it clear which urls (absolute urls) are supposed to be served as post list and specific post.